# How to initialise cache when deploying a flask application on apache

Tags: python, apache, flask

I need to deploy a flask application on a Apache server and i mainly followed this guide:

I would like to do the following:
 - run 3 database queries
 - initialise a cache with the results of these queries

When testing the app on the local server i normally include the initialisation in the startServer method (as shown below) but i understand that the method does not get run when deploying on apache.

```
def startServer():

    app.secret_key = 'super_secret_key'
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
    cache.set('galleries', getTable(Gallery))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        startServer()
```

Does anyone know what would be the best way to to initialise the cache when launching the server rather waiting for a request?

Please note that i am using sql alchemy and the database connection is not yet available at the the the wsgi file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the flask webapp file, the one imported in the WSGI script, where:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

# Cache seeding
cache.set('galleries', getTable(Gallery))
```

Caution - this will set the cache on every import of the webapp, not just once. Multiple WSGI processes will run query and set cache multiple times.

Consider out of process synchronisation if that is not desirable, as provided by the [`fcntl` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fcntl.html?module-fcntl) for example.

Comment: Thank you Danny, after thinking about this a bit more and doing some more research it appears to me that what i was trying to do was wrong anyway because, as you said, the cache would be initialised with every request. It seems to me that the correct approach is to set up a memcache and use that in my application.

Comment: On every WSGI process, not every request, but yes agree that memcache is a better approach.